# Deleted/Added a DNS host entry to access a network share: path not found

Tags: windows, dns, network-shares, netbios

I was requested to delete a host record (a CIF server on a NAS) I haven't deleted the AD account, only the DNS host record. Then I added the same host record with a different IP address which belongs to another computer. This other computer is a member server of the domain. Whenever I try to access a network share or any command that uses the netbios name I am getting network path not found. (test done from a Win2k8) If I do it from a Windows XP machine outside the domain providing credentials I am able to access the network share.

So should I delete the computer account (I did not want to do that yet). I know there is a way to use cnames instead of host A records for this purpose, not sure if I will get the same issue as the computer account is still there in AD.

Could you provide your thoughts? Anyone else had a similar case like this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush your DNS cache? 
I run into this problem a lot when waking up a bunch of VMs.